# Using Intel Vtune to profile Application from Qt Creator

Tags: c++, windows, qt, profiling, intel-vtune

**I want to profile application from QtCreator using Vtune on Windows 7**. But Vtune is basicaly made for Visual Studio Apps, so I have to make the link between my function's names and the instruction in release build.
Actually I have only pseudo names func@address in Hotspots ,its not usable.

By exploring the "Getting Started" from Intel Vtune I find that **I must enable the Debug Information in my release build but How to perform that in QtCreator?**

From 'Using Debug Information' File:

> To provide accurate performance data and enable source analysis, the
>   Intel® VTune™ Amplifier requires debug information for the binary
>   files it analyzes. If it does not find debug information in the
>   binaries, the VTune Amplifier statically identifies function
>   boundaries and assigns hotspot addresses to generated pseudo names
>   func@address for such functions.
>
> If debug information is absent, the Call Stack pane may not unwind the
>   call stack correctly for user-mode sampling and tracing analysis
>   types. Additionally in some cases, it can take significantly more time
>   to finalize the results for modules that do not have debug
>   information.
>
> On Windows* operating systems, PDB files provide debug information.
>   Make sure both your system and application libraries/executable have
>   PDB files. Compile your target with optimizations and start profiling
>   its performance.
>
> By default, the Microsoft Visual Studio* IDE does not generate PDB
>   information in the Release mode. For better results with the VTune
>   Amplifier, enable symbol generation manually. For system libraries,
>   use the Microsoft* Symbol Server to download the required PDB files
>   from the Microsoft* web site. Follow the steps below to ensure the
>   VTune Amplifier uses debug information for both system and your own
>   libraries.

I try some methods like: -edit the file.pro to change the release build

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -g
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -g
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE =
```

- profile the Debug build.

but it doesn't change anything, i still haven't the function name printed

Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for VTune (or other similar profiling tools) you need "release build" (i.e. optimization switched ON) with debug information switched ON as well. QTCreator doesn't create this kind of release+debug configuration by default.

For Windows MS compiler toolchain case it implies that you have to *supplement* Release configuration with *additional*  /Zi compilation and /DEBUG linker options.

In order to propagate these additional options in QTCreator **use following steps** (see also screen-shot below):

- Open qtcreator project file (***.pro) in editor
- Add following lines before "TARGET"

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-Zi`
`QMAKE_LFLAGS+=/DEBUG`

- Now, when building your project, these options will be automatically applied to both Debug and Release configuration (Debug already has it, so it should not be a problem)
- Now you can profile your release build using VTune

Few more *minor* notes:

1. Similar procedure (with QMAKE_CXXFLAGS) is also applicable to MinGW/GCC or any other toolchains with appropriate options (-g, -gdwarf-2, etc)
2. If you don't want to impact all configurations, there are QT project pragmas allowing to conditionalize QMAKE_CXXFLAGS between configurations
3. If you want to profile QT standard libraries internals, then you will additionally have to link with debug versions of QT libraries, by adjusting QMAKE_LFLAGS with extra  options like /DQT***; you can learn these from looking at QT "compiler output" window when building default Debug configurations.

[image: QT creator Screen-shot]

Comment: Thank you, I have already find a pseudo solution and your answer help me to complete it. Now I can have the QT standard libraries internals it will be great!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you use VTun eupdate 7 or later
2. If you are using default MinGW toolchain make sure you use DWARF debug format by passing -gdwarf-2 (or -g3 -gdwarf-2)
3. If you are using MSVC toolchain /Zi shuld be passed to the compiler and /DEBUG to the linker